# Creating Vertices and Edges in Apache Spark results in error: recursive value fields needs type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am learning Apache Spark using the Ampcamp exercises at http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html

I am trying to create a Graph using the example of chapter 4.2 using my own data files for Vertices and Edges. My Vertex table consist out of 12 columns 0 to 11. Column 11 stores the Vertex IDs. My code is to almost equivalent to the Amplab example but results into an error 18:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
val thoughts: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/user/hue/thoughts_long.txt")
val vertices = thoughts.map { line => val fields = line.split('\t') (fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2)) }

<console>:18: error: recursive value fields needs type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you forgot `;`  : `line => val fields = line.split('\t'); (fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `;`:

```
{ line => val fields = line.split('\t'); (fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2) }
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{ 
  line => val fields = line.split('\t');
  (fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2);
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{ 
  line => val fields = line.split('\t')
  (fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2)
}
```

Scala doesn't require `;` between expressions, unless you write them in one line. The code from example does 2 things:

1. assigns the value: `val fields = line.split('\t')`
2. returns a tuple based on this value: `(fields(11).toLong, fields(1), fields(2)`

So it's different expressions which should be separated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did know that the ; is not mandatory in Scala as is it in Java. But is makes reading and copying code a lot more complex to a Scala rookie like me. :)